# EFCore some Properties aren't populated

Tags: entity-framework-core, include, ef-core-6.0

Im having the problem that some of my objects aren't populated fully and I can't understand why this happens I tested with the following code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Artikel/Test")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
    {
        return Json(await db.Artikel_Meldungen
            .Include(m => m.Meldung).ThenInclude(a => a.ErsatzArtikel)
            .Where(x=>x.Artikel_MeldungId==1726)
            .ToListAsync());
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Artikel/Meldung")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetMeldungen()
    {
        return Json((await db.Artikel_Meldungen
            .Include(m => m.Meldung).ThenInclude(a => a.ErsatzArtikel)
            .ToListAsync())
            .Where(x => x.Artikel_MeldungId == 1726));
    }
```

with the following classes:

```
[Table("Meldung", Schema = "BDB")]
public class Meldung
{
    [Key]
    public int Meldung_Id { get; set; }
    public string Erfasser { get; set; }
    public Artikel ErsatzArtikel { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Artikel Parent { get; set; }
    public long ErsatzArtNr { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(2)")]
    public string ErsatzAusfKz { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Artikel_Meldung> Artikel_Meldungen { get; set; }
    public string Kommentar { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartZeitpunkt { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndeZeitpunkt { get; set; }
}

[Table("Artikel_Meldung", Schema = "BDB")]
public class Artikel_Meldung
{
    [Key]
    public int Artikel_MeldungId { get; set; }
    public int Meldung_Id { get; set; }
    public Meldung Meldung { get; set; }
    public Artikel Artikel { get; set; }
    public long ArtNr { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(2)")]
    public string Ausfkz { get; set; }
}
[Table("Artikeldaten_PRE", Schema = "BDB")]
public class Artikel
{
    [Key]
    public long ArtNr { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(2)")]
    public string AusfKz { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Artikel_Meldung> Artikel_Meldungen { get; set; }
}
```

As for my understanding both should return the same result. But for some reason the "Artikel/Meldung" endpoint isn't populating the ErsatzArtikel object. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Regards Martin

Comment: Side note: of course `Artikel/Test` is the endpoint that you should use (Where before ToListAsync). Also, why do you use `Json(...)`? As for the issue, looks like a bug. Which exact EF version is this? Try what happens when you add `AsNoTracking` (which is recommended anyway in a disconnected scenario).

Comment: I want to retrieve all objects without the filter. The added where clause was only for visualizing the article I found wasn't fully populated. Im using EFCore 6.04. and Json to get a proper IActionResult compatible object. But adding AsSplitQuery and AsNoTracking did the trick. Of course all other endpoints using also AsNoTracking but here it seems I forgot to add it. Thanks for the advice @GertArnold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding AsNoTracking() AsSplitQuery() fixed the issue